# Redirect not working django

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-views, django-urls

I've a problem about Django URL-redirection. The structure of the code is the following :

- The reactor view displays an HTML page with a list of elements. When clicking on one of them, an ajax request is done to the view.
- The ajax request is calling an another view with necessary informations
- The measurementReactor is called and displays details about one reactor.

All functions are correctly called, the GET request is done but the page doesn't redirect in browser...

[image]

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^reactors/$', views.reactors, name = 'reactors'),
     url(r'^measurements/reactor/$', views.measurementReactor, name='measureReact'),
]
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def reactor(request):
if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
    if request.POST.get('type') == "measurement" :
        return redirect('/measurements/reactor/?ref='+request.POST.get('id'))

@login_required
def measurementReactor(request):
    reactobj = reactor.objects.get(id=request.GET['ref'])
    query = measurements.objects.filter(id_reactor=reactobj.id)

    return render(request, "measureReact.html",{"query":query})
```

reactor.js

```
var table1 = $('#datatable').DataTable();

$('#datatable tbody').on('click', 'tr>th:not(.controls.mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric)', function () {
var data = $(this).parent().find("[name=pk]").text();
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  data : {'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : csrftoken, 'id':data, 'type':"measurement"},
 });
});
```

[EDIT] Thank you for your answers, i did this and it works !

```
#views.py
import json
@login_required
def reactors(request):
    if request.POST.get('type') == "measurement" :
        data = json.dumps({'url':'/measurements/reactor/?ref='+request.POST.get('id')})
        return HttpResponse(data)

#reactor.js
$.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      data : {'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : csrftoken, 'id':data, 'type':"measurement"},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
        window.location.href = data["url"];
      }
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ajax call you will get the data in json format, it will not change the url, better return the url on json fromt using HttpResponse and redirect that url from the javascript code.

```
@login_required
def reactor(request):
if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
    import josn
    if request.POST.get('type') == "measurement" :
        data = josn.dump({'url':/measurements/reactor/?ref='+request.POST.get('id')})
        return HttpResponse(data)
```

in the ajax call success method, catch the response and redirect using $window

Answer (score 0):

As *aman kumar* suggested, your reactor view should return `url` back to reactor.js and then use it to redirect to the desired page:

## reactor.js

```
var table1 = $('#datatable').DataTable();

$('#datatable tbody').on('click', 'tr>th:not(.controls.mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric)', function () {
var data = $(this).parent().find("[name=pk]").text();
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  data : {'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : csrftoken, 'id':data, 'type':"measurement"},
  success: function(data){
    window.location.href = data.url;
  }
 });
});
```